# C# WPF Display large xml file of unknown format

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, stack-overflow

I'm trying to parse an XML file of size around 400KB. But I cannot overcome the stack overflow exception.  First I create XmlReader and pass it to the XML file. Then I create XElement from the XmlReader. [image]

This is my code:

```
private ViewContent ParseToView(XElement xElement)
{
    ViewContent viewContent = new ViewContent();
    viewContent.elementName = xElement.Name.LocalName;
        foreach (XAttribute item in xElement.Attributes())
        {
            viewContent.attributes.Add(new ElementAttribute(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value));
        }
        foreach (XElement item in xElement.Elements())
        {
            viewContent.viewContents.Add(ParseToView(xElement));
        }
        return new ViewContent();
    }

}

public class ViewContent
{
    public string elementName;
    public List<ElementAttribute> attributes = new List<ElementAttribute>();
    public List<ViewContent> viewContents = new List<ViewContent>();
} 

public class ElementAttribute
{
    public ElementAttribute(string attributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

    public string attributeName;
    public string attributeValue;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `ParseToView` - which isn't parsing anything anyway, it only converts one type of classes to another. Since you already use LINQ-to-XML you could use LINQ to generate the ViewModel classes from the XElement data. Or you could bind directly to the data. After all, ViewContent and ElementAttribute contain the same things the parsed classes do. Why duplicate the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `ParseToView` you are calling same method recursively but you're calling it with same parameter - `viewContent.viewContents.Add(ParseToView(xElement));` - this causes stackoverflow:

```
viewContent.viewContents.Add(ParseToView(xElement));
```

should have probably been:

```
viewContent.viewContents.Add(ParseToView(item));
```

in method:

```
private ViewContent ParseToView(XElement xElement)
{
    ViewContent viewContent = new ViewContent();
    viewContent.elementName = xElement.Name.LocalName;
        foreach (XAttribute item in xElement.Attributes())
        {
            viewContent.attributes.Add(new ElementAttribute(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value));
        }
        foreach (XElement item in xElement.Elements())
        {
            viewContent.viewContents.Add(ParseToView(xElement)); // <-Faulty line here
        }
        return new ViewContent();
    }

}
```